# Why do I get the error "Expression must have class type but it has type Calculator(*)()" when I create an object?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Context:

I am learning C++ and came across the concept of delegating constructors and also member initializer lists. I was creating a very basic calculator class and I came across the error message "Expression must have class type but it has type Calculator(*)()" when creating an object.

The code for my class is

```
class Calculator 
{

    float num1;
    float num2;

public:
    
    Calculator() : Calculator(0, 0){}
    Calculator(float n1) : Calculator(n1, 0){}
    Calculator(float n1, float n2): num1(n1), num2(n2){}

    //declaring the facilitators
    float add(float n1, float n2);
    float subtract(float n1, float n2);
    float multiply(float n1, float n2);
    float divide(float n1, float n2);

    //destructor
    ~Calculator() {
        std::cout << "Object destroyed" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The member functions are not causing any issue so I will leave out their definitions

Within the main function(), when I create my object as

Calculator obj;
My program works and I can use the obj to access all the member functions. However, when I write

Calculator obj();
I get the error specified in the title.

I am confused as to why this happens. Shouldn't the default constructor (and then the third constructor through delegation) be invoked in both cases?

Comment: Because `Calculator obj();` declares a function named `obj`, which takes no parameters, and returns a `Calculator`. Google "the most vexing parse".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I googled most vexing parse as you said and it seems like this occurs only when there are no arguments? Passing arguments apparently invokes the constructor. I am not able to understand why there is this difference in the syntax though

Comment: Because e.g. `Calculator obj(42);` can't possibly be interpreted as a valid function declaration; but `Calculator obj();` can.

Comment: @Mole_Boy `inf f()` declares a function of no parameter returning an int, this syntax is the same for every possible return type, so `Calculator obj()` is a function of no parameter returning a Calculator. `int i` defines an int, `Calculator c` defines a Calculator.